# Copy + paste out of a Flex DataGrid control

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, copy-paste

Is there a way to select a single cell in a Flex DataGrid, and then either select the text inside of the cell, or select the entire cell for copy + paste? It doesn't even have to copy into an excel friendly format, flat text would be fine. So far, I have only been able to select an entire row, and that doesn't seem to copy very well. I am using a DataGrid to display an error log, and I would like to be able to Copy the stack trace information out and throw it in a bug report or an email.

Thanks.

Comment: You can select the test from a `DataGrid` with `editable="true"` : but that's a workaround - not a solution.

Comment: I would rather not have the data be user-editable, but it is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works great for me: 
http://hillelcoren.com/2009/09/17/import-export-copy-paste-flex-datagrid/

Answer (score 1):

So after reading through the article Mike Sickler posted. I found some more posts on copying out of Flex (and Flash). See [here](http://mannu.livejournal.com/348299.html) and [here](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=149946). It looks like the best way is to create a hidden div on the page that you place your copied text into on Ctrl + C, and then putting that on the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Muller has provided an excellent post and sample code on how to do this with the Spark DataGrid

http://hansmuller-flex.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/datagrid-support-for-copy-and-paste.html